# Linear Layout not clickable in Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout

I recently upgraded my Android studio 4.1, I have been doing a project where I use LinearLayout as a button with a drawable ripple effect on click. This method works smoothly in the older version. Now that I upgraded and created a new project, the Layout (Button) doesn't show the ripple effect. Does Anyone know why?

PS: The same code was working before I updated the android studio.

neoback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btnsslcut"/>
</ripple>
```

Activity.xml

````
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/backgroundgrey"
    tools:context=".dashboardUI">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/btnback"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/neoback"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="26dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icback"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-3dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>```
````

Comment: where you are using ripple.xml?? plz share complete code

Comment: @drawable/neoback as a background in the linear layout

Comment: Can you try the following? android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground" /// foreground or background